# NIO: OP_READ and not reading all data; does OP_READ remain in ready set?

Tags: java, nio

Imagine a socket channel with 32KB socket receive buffer.

24KB of data is being received and the OP_READ is set in the ready set and an IO thread gets notified to process the incoming data.

Normally the socketchannel.read is called with a bytebuffer that is able to fully store the content of the socket receive buffer.

But now my question:

What happens when the bytebuffer isn't big enough to read all the data,e.g. a bytebuffer of 16KB, and therefor 8KB remain in the socket receive buffer. Will the OP_READ be removed from the ready set or does the OP_READ remain in the ready set as long as data remains in socket-buffer of the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Normally the socketchannel.read is called with a bytebuffer that is able to fully store the content of the socket receive buffer.

No it isn't. It is called with a `ByteBuffer` that is large enough to receive whatever the application is ready to receive at this time.

> What happens when the bytebuffer isn't big enough to read all the data,e.g. a bytebuffer of 16KB, and therefor 8KB remain in the socket receive buffer. Will the OP_READ be removed from the ready set

No.

> or does the OP_READ remain in the ready set as long as data remains in socket-buffer of the socket.

No, it is removed from the ready set when you remove it, as you must, but if there is still data in the socket receive buffer on the next `select()` it is *restored* to the ready set.